# loosing input chars in dynamic php mysql lookup

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I am trying to do a part lookup system (which mostly works), but I am loosing some chars in the PHP var (only sometimes).
If I type in 1234 in the text box, the text box will always show the full number I type in.

But, the results part will show numbers starting with 1234 for a split second, then it will loose the 4, then it will loose the 3, then it will loose the 2, and then it shows partno's starting with 1 and that will stay. Most of the time it is so fast it looks like it just drops all numbers at once, but I watch real close and its droping one char at a time.

output to screen -- for testing
js var partno shows 1234
js var idxno shows  1234
php var idxno shows 1

(this number 1234 is only an example, I use random partno's from 3 to 20 chars and when it drops chars it always leaves the first char enterd.)

If I use the backspace key to remove the 4 then the 23 will come back and I can enter 4 again and the php var idxno will show 1234 like it should.
If I restart the server it will always happen the first time I enter a part number, sometimes the second and third time, then it may work fine for 10 to 20 more lookups and then will do it again, it is never really consistent.
If I run this query on an empty database it works fine, Never drops the numbers.
If I remove the 'ORDER BY' clause it will almost always drop all chars except the first one.
I have this basic code running now on my first draft of this program with all manufactures in separate databases and it works great. I am trying to combine all manufactures into one database file and this when the problem started.
With separate manufactures the largest price list is probably around 150,000 rows.
With all manufactures combined it is around 750,000 rows now, and will be a little over 1,000,000 rows when done.

I am running:
Debian Wheezy 7.2
Apache version 2.2.22
MySQL version 5.5.38
PHP Version 5.4.4-14+deb7u14

I am using a Virtualbox server to write and test code, But I put this on a real server on the lan and it does exactly the same.

I hope I gave enough info for this problem, This is my first attempt at a real program as such, and I cannot figure a way to troubleshoot what is happening, I have been at this for months and for the first time, finally decided to ask for help.

Thanks for any help I can get.

index.php

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js_php/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var npage = 0;
function part_lookup(cnt){
    var action = "lookup";
    var partno = document.getElementById("partno").value;
    var idxno = partno.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9%]/g,'');
        if (cnt == 'next') {npage = npage + 15;}
        else if (cnt == 'prev') {npage = npage - 15;}
        else {npage = 0;}
            if (npage < 0) {npage = 0;}
        $.post("js_php/partlookup.php", {action:action, idxno:idxno, npage:npage},
         function(data){$("#part_data").html(data);});
    }
</script>
</head>
<?php
    $whereami='home';
//   include("page_setup.php");
?>
<!--body-->      <!--code will not validate w3c with this body tag, says tag already open ??-->
<div id="lookup">
    <div>
        <input id="Prev" type="button" value="Previous Page" onclick="part_lookup('prev')">
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input id="partno" type="text" name="partno" maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" autofocus onclick="this.value = ''" onkeyup="part_lookup()">
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
        <input id="Next" type="button" value="   Next Page   " onclick="part_lookup('next')"> 
    </div>
</div>
<div id="part_data"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

partlookup.php

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

include("db_connect.vars.php");
// Make a MySQLi Connection
$db_connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
if (!$db_connect) {die('Connect Error ('.mysqli_connect_errno().') '.mysqli_connect_error());}
/*********************************************************************/
$idxno = $_POST['idxno'];
$page = $_POST['npage'];
echo "idxno = ".'<b>'.$idxno.'</b><br/>';
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect,
   "SELECT PriceList.*, Inventory.instk AS instk, Inventory.ovrstk AS ovrstk, Inventory.used AS used
   FROM PriceList
   LEFT JOIN Inventory ON PriceList.mfg = Inventory.mfg 
   AND PriceList.idxno = Inventory.idxno
   WHERE PriceList.idxno LIKE '$idxno%'
   ORDER BY PriceList.idxno
   LIMIT $page,15");
mysqli_close($db_connect);
?>
```

OK, I did as Jeff suggested I hope,

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

and then looked at '/var/lib/mysql/debian-7.log' file, This is the results

```
141012 18:07:30   148 Connect   root@localhost on lawn2
          148 Query
          149 Connect   root@localhost on lawn2
          149 Query 
          149 Quit  
          150 Connect   root@localhost on lawn2
          150 Query 
          150 Quit  
          151 Connect   root@localhost on lawn2
          151 Query 
          151 Quit  
141012 18:07:31   148 Quit
```

There is a 148 Quit after a 151 Quit,
So I added a `mysqli_close($db_connect);` at the end of partlookup.php file.

but it made no difference, still having same problem.

Comment: I would write the sql statement out to a log file to check that things were ok on that front.

Comment: Just a guess: change this call `function(data){$("#part_data").html(data);` to return a constant instead of a lookup. I'm suspicious that it isn't being used correctly.

Comment: This code `function(data){$("#part_data").html(data);` currently does not return any data, except for value of idxno from the php file. currently I am simply passing var idxno to partlookup.php and running mysql query, no data being returned for testing, except for current value of idxno.

Comment: I think what Jeff was saying is that you should log the actual SQL queries being executed, so you can see exactly what's getting queried.    

Also, you really need to fix your query variables, they are just waiting to be attacked with a SQL injection hack. 
    
Instead of `LIKE '$idxno%'` You should instead be writing:  `LIKE '".mysqli_real_escape_string($db_connect, $idxno)."%'`

Comment: OK, I figured out what is happening so I will answer my own question next. As far as SQL injection, would not this JS code not fix it;  `var partno = document.getElementById("partno").value;`  `var idxno = partno.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9%]/g,'');`

Comment: @JimmyA you need to take care of SQL injections server-side, there's no point in doing it in JS since that executes on the client and a malicious client would obviously bypass that.

Comment: Ahh!! that makes since to me -- Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found out what is happening using Firebug and enabling Net tab.
I can Type in a part number of 1234, and the PHP file sends the request to the server in separate connections. ??

1        takes 3.02s to complete
12       takes 1.03s to complete
123      takes 855ms to complete
1234     takes 12ms  to complete

So now 1234 information shows up, then
the 123 info shows up, then
the 12 info shows up, then
the 1 info shows up.

Since it takes less than a second to type in the part number,
I am Left with part numbers starting with a 1 showing in the returned info.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to Optimize the Query or cancel a previous. Query or just add inventory info into the pricelist file, but that will create some additional problems to deal with.

Thanks to everyone who responded to this question.